# DataTable unique constraint - raise event

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I created a DataTable which 1st column is set to Unique.
When I insert a new row or modify a row, whenever the unique constraint is violated, a little "!" appears on the left. However, I would like my table to either raise an event or an exception.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, on the left, right before the 1st row

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use RowChanged event. In the handler you can get e.Row.HasErrors. That should be enough.

Comment: Do I have to check row by row if the constraint is violated?

Comment: I have editet my answer. I don't have the right enviroment to test it, but an idea should be enough. If RowChanged does not work try with RowChanging, because I am not sure when HasErrors will be set.

Comment: This is weird, when there is no error, RowChanged/RowChanging is triggered. But when there is one, it is not triggered.

Comment: In that case I suggest you to use validation rules.

Comment: I can fire the the RowEditEnding event from DataGrid, but there is no "RowEditEnded" event, as I need to get the cell value AFTER it is updated. Any ideas? I'll try to look upon validation rules thought

Comment: Problem is, the framework doesn't allow the actual data to be transfered into a data table. It inercepts the data, just like validation rule does. I personaly didn't find better solution than validation rules.